# Flutter is not working anymore, Xcode build taking very long, then fails

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am working on a project and everything seemed to work fine.
The app ran fine on a iPhone 12 simulator and on my personal device.
Out of the sudden everything stopped working and I get weird error messages.
I think what happened is, that I tried to commit changes to Flutter itself because I clicked on the small branch icon in VScode.

Now the problem is, that the Xcode Build is taking very long and then fails after a long time when I try to debug and run the project.
There are no errors in the debug console.

I ran flutter doctor in my project file:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H1030 darwin-x64, locale de-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.59.1)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I had the Flutter version 2.0.0 before I think.

This is what my VScode bottom bar is showing:
[image]

I think there is something wrong with the repository.
I haven't uploaded anything to GitHub yet.
Maybe I need to quit out of the branch or something.
How can I resolve these issues?
I am not an expert but maybe there's an expert here who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem on my own.
The only thing I did was this:
Go to the terminal in VScode.
Move inside the project directory.
Then type:

```
flutter downgrade v2.0.1
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

Now I'm on version 2.0.6 somehow and the simulator is showing the app again.